# Как std::string присвоить значение содержащееся в BYTE*

Tags: c++

у меня в BYTE* содержится значение которое мне нужно присвоить std::string как я могу это сделать? Например что-то вроде

```
BYTE* str1 = (BYTE*)"anton";
```

Comment: `std::string s((const char*)str1);` если я все правильно понял

Comment: Так как метка С++, я бы сказал:    `std::string(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(str1));`

Comment: я бы посмотрел для начала, что там в BYTE, может это и есть char. Во вторых, ещё не известно, есть ли там финальный ноль

Comment: @KoVadim Если `"anton"` - то таки есть...

Comment: В этом случае есть, но тогда возникает законный вопрос, а зачем кастить это к `(BYTE*)`

Answer (score -2, accepted):

`BYTE` это одно и тоже с `unsigned char`.

То есть задача сводится к тому, чтобы преобразовать `unsigned char*` в `string`.

Это можно сделать явно преобразовав `unsigned char* str1` к типу `char*`.

**WARNING**  Строка `str1` **должна** заканчивается нулем (`'\0'`)

Например так:

```
string str((const char*)str1); //Передать в конструктор
string str = (const char*)str1; //Через оператор присваивания
```

Или использовать преобразование типов в стиле `c++` при помощи функции `reinterpret_cast<T>()`:

```
string str(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(str1)); //Передать в конструктор
string str = reinterpret_cast<const char*>(str1); //Через оператор присваивания
```

О преобразовании `char*` в `string` на enSO: [ссылка](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1673445/how-to-convert-unsigned-char-to-stdstring-in-c)

И как дополнение.

Разница между первым и вторым вариантом преобразования: [ссылка](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7831696/reinterpret-cast-vs-c-style-cast)

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118393/discussion-on-answer-by----stdstring---).

Comment: А разве здесь `string str = (const char*)str1; //Через оператор присваивания` присваивание, а не конструирование?..

Comment: @Mikhailo Оператор конструирования? Максимум я забыл про то, что в данном случае вызывается конструктор инициализации. Но это не критично т.к. все равно через оператор присваивания происходит инициализация.

Comment: Я плохо, наверное, пояснил. Здесь `string str = (const char*)str1;` оператор присваивания (`operator =()`) не вызывается. Хоть вы и пишете `//Через оператор присваивания`.

Comment: @Mikhailo "_Максимум я забыл про то, что в данном случае вызывается конструктор инициализации. Но это не критично т.к. все равно через оператор присваивания происходит инициализация._"